# When does SSD static wear leveling operation occur, possible to measure?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, trim

Scenario:

> 1) New 60GB SSD Drive
>
> 2) Install OS and Programs 40G
>
> 3) Assume windows pagefile.sys file size is 16G
>
> 4) The bulk of the OS and Programs are rarely (if ever) updated for 5 years.

Since the sectors for the OS and Programs are written to just once and unavailable then that the effective number of sectors available to the swap for continuous trim/reuse is much smaller.

It seems to correct this there is the concept of [static wear leveling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling) from this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/189002/261679).

Is there are way to verify that this feature is available for a given drive or when it happens or monitor/measure the effect?

Comment: You might be interested in reading a study by Google that indicated age is a bigger factor in SSD failure than use is: https://www.yahoo.com/tech/doesn-t-kill-solid-state-202347715.html

Comment: Similar [question](http://superuser.com/questions/902698/how-does-ssd-achieve-wear-leveling-when-disk-is-near-full?rq=1)